# Why does it say that my app is superseded?

Tags: android, google-play, release, publish, production

I am trying to publish an app to google play store. I have uploaded versions to Internal testing which works fine, but when I upload to Production, it says "release not live". When I go to "release details" it says "superseded". I know it is superseded if there is a higher version code in e.g. internal testing, but this is not the case. We have checked so many times, but the production always have the highest version code. Does anyone know any other reasons why it is superseded?

It says superseded immediately after we upload the APK from Android Studio.

Additional information regarding the app: it is an Android Automotive application.

"Production - Inactive"
[image]

"Production - Superseded "

[image]

"Internal testing"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out we had to go to "manage form factors" (which can be found in the field where you choose between Standard and Automotive OS only). Then we had to agree to terms and conditions of the Android Automotive program. This fixed the issue for us, and the status was no longer "superseded".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the track was paused, I unpaused it and it was labelled "active", but it actually wasn't. I had to submit the unpause action for review first.
Once the track was really unpaused it changed from superseded to active